# only certain Youtube url 's are getting played in ios

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i m parsing youtube json feed in iphone.i m playing the video in webview.since youtube video's doesnt MPMovieplayerController.i using webView to play the video but the problem is only certain videos are getting played and certain other not.below is the code

```
  - (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame {  
NSString* embedHTML = @"\ 
<html><head>\ 
<style type=\"text/css\">\ 
body {\ 
    background-color: transparent;\ 
color: white;\ 
}\ 
</style>\ 
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\ 
<embed id=\"yt\"src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"\ 
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\ 
</body></html>";  
NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];  

[youTubeWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];  
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error saying this video is not available?

Comment: i m not getting any error..i m getting a cancelled play button

Comment: Show me one that does, and one that doesn't work.

Comment: i ll post u the url...one sec

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/v/NoUQLGU9Ysk?version=3&f=user_uploads&app=youtube_gdata...this play.http://www.youtube.com/v/7edVcVRCyZQ?version=3&f=user_uploads&app=youtube_gdata..this doesnt

Comment: one more thing i m testing this in ipad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Videos can be enabled/disabled for mobile users in the youtube video settings.

Source: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/3_LkO_ap0_Q

Here is link to Google explaining [Common Questions About Distribution Settings](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2453875).

Answer (score 0):

At least when browsing, some videos are not playable on mobile. It could be the wrong format, blocked from the iPhone by the user when they uploaded it, or blocked from the iPhone by Apple.

Comment: I agree with the first part, but I don't think Apple blocks certain videos.  If that was the case, nobody would be able to watch p0rn.

Comment: This is what I was able to discover from personal experience and a brief internet trawl. My guess is that 'Apple blocked from iPhone' meant certain formats they didn't like that _could_ play.